# Django+Nginx+Gunicorn loading larger files

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I have search and tried many things but can't seem to find a similar case.
My setup:
Django + nginx + gunicorn on ubuntu 16.04.1

The issue:
I have a site that allow internal user to upload zip file to server. The upload uses HTML with POST to read and save the file to server, nothing fancy. The application works great with smaller files (~30 mb is the largest I tested). When larger files are loading you will see the status going from 0% to x% then restart at 0% again, it will do this twice then I will get an error. Timing this, each interval is at 30 seconds which led me to conclude that it is gunicorn that is timing out.

The question:
I setup my service to execute this way:

```
/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --timeout 240 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/myproj/myapp.sock myproj.wsgi:application
```

No matter what I try, it still reset at 30 seconds. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought it might be the timeout value but you've set that - sorry, didn't notice that till after I posted it. It's possible that the problem lies in your Nginx config as that has an upload limit too. Also, how are you running the Gunicorn process? Did you stop and restart it correctly?

Comment: As 30 seconds is the default timeout for Gunicorn the most likely reason I can think of for it still using that is either the Gunicorn process not being restarted or the timeout field not being picked up due to a configuration error. Are you using something like Supervisor to run it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. I have checked my Nginx settings. I set the timeout to 700s. I am not using Supervisor.